# Store a range to a numpy array in an object and reuse it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code, where I create views to `numpy` arrays and then assign one view with the other. I was wondering if it is possible to create objects that define a certain range in the array and then use that object to index the array. I wrote some meta code in the comments that show the idea.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

itot = 6
jtot = 4

a = 1*np.ones((jtot, itot))
b = 2*np.ones((jtot, itot))

# I can create a view.
a_left = a[:,0]
b_left = b[:,0]

# But is a solution like this possible?
# left = ...
# a_left = a[left]
# b_left = b[left]

a_left[:] = b_left[:]

plt.pcolormesh(a)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think that this is a more generic question, whereas the duplicate is a very complex usecase.

Comment: The same tool applies. We don't need a different question for every possible complexity level of the slice argument.